# Kaspersky kavremvr.exe removed start menu entries

Tags: windows-10, kaspersky

Today i tried to unistall Kaspersky Internet Security with the provided kavremvr.exe from Kaspersky.
After the unistalling procedure finished and restarting the computer i saw that the start menu was nearly empty.
I took a look into the log file and saw that the Kavremvr tool deleted the start menu entry.

```
1636:3144 20:43:20.994 Folder will be deleted on reboot: C:\Program Files (x86)\Kaspersky Lab

1636:3144 20:43:20.994 File deleted: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\\Accessibility\desktop.ini
1636:3144 20:43:20.994 File deleted: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\\Accessibility\Speech Recognition.lnk
1636:3144 20:43:20.994 File deleted: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\\Accessories\desktop.ini
1636:3144 20:43:20.994 File deleted: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\\Accessories\Math Input Panel.lnk
....
```

Is anyone having the same problem?

Best regards

Comment: Have you contacted Kaspersky support or checked their forums?

Comment: Also, if you're asking for help to solve a problem, please present that problem and give us a clear question. This isn't a forum where general queries can be discussed.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @music2myear. I contacted the support and send them the complete log. But my request wasn't answered.
My question was if anyone having the same problem. But i think i wrote it to the wrong forum, because its more like a general question.

Comment: Superuser is a site for specific questions that can get specific answers. Your question isn't bad, but it is better served on a forum where open discussion is the norm and expected.